# Why does .isHidden cause a dissolve animation?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerlayer

I have the bellow line:

```
  playerLayer.isHidden = true
```

For some reason when its called, the playerLayer does a dissolve animation out.

**Why does this happen and how can I prevent that?**

Declaration of player layer.

```
        media.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: media.playerQueue)
```

Comment: Can you post the `playerLayer`'s declaration?

Comment: See update, @Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this happen

Because animation is the default when setting a layer property.

> and how can I prevent that?

Use CATransaction to disable animation.

Comment: Look in the CATransaction documentation. Begin, disable animations, set isHidden, commit. Easy.